# can't load php file with jquery and access variable outside the file

Tags: php, jquery

If I load my php file (Home.php) via Jquery, I can't seem to be able to access $var in my Home.php file. It loads succesfuly but I get this "undefined" error:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: var in /media/sf_sandbox/linksup/view/Home.php
```

I have done this in this exact same order.
I declare the variable:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $var = "bar";
?>
```

I load the file Home.php with .load():

**index.php**

```
<div id="ContentContainer">
    <script>        
        $( "#ContentContainer" ).load( "view/Home.php" );
    </script>
</div>
```

I then try to get the value of $var in Home.php:

**Home.php**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <?php echo $var?>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to load a php file from a JS file? More likely you mean that you want to call a URL which happens to point to a resource delivered by PHP routine? But then, the resulting resource is not a PHP file but a rendered HTML for example, or JSON, or HTML that contains JS elements, or a plain JS file etc.

Comment: Why you don't want to use ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using jquery for that purpose. PHP `include_once()` will do that easily.

**In `Home.php` do like below:-**

```
<?php include_once('index.php');?>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <?php echo $var?>
        </div>
</div>
```